# How to debug SSH sessions to print shared key etc

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am writing an SSH client using only bash (as much as possible) and need to compare the keys found by me, with the right keys (like using wireshark for debugging SSL)

There is currently no solution that I know, that can do this

Here is [code](http://code.google.com/p/bassh-secure-shell-in-bash/)

Is there a way to decrypt ssh keys and print them (even if it is a custom ssh server with a debug option to print the keys, it would be fine)

Comment: Do you mean the symmetric session keys, or the public/private login keys?

Comment: *"I am writing an SSH client using only bash"* - that's NUTS!

Comment: echo "#!/bin/sh\n ssh \$@" > ssh.sh

Comment: It is shared key, client write key, read key etc

Comment: Any idea where the linux ssh source is taken from (openssh.org sources at http://www.openssh.com/portable.html don't compile)

Comment: I am getting the keys now, but I want to know what is the formula for deriving client write key, client read key etc from the hash; I read it as: SHA1(K + H + 'C' + H) and similarly with replacements of C with D, E and F for various other keys

Comment: Just put in a few debug statements in OpenSSH source code to print all the keys in the key material; Here is the link in case it helps someone: http://code.google.com/p/bassh-secure-shell-in-bash/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fopenssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My amateurish debug statements in openssh source:

http://code.google.com/p/bassh-secure-shell-in-bash/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fopenssh

Answer (score 1):

There are codelines for debuging in the sourcefile that are responsible for your DH Keyexchange.

E.g.

`in kexc25519s.c(=key exchange curve 255519 server) line 56: #ifdef DEBUG_KEXECDH dump_digest("server private key:....`

So write `#define DEBUG_KEXECDH 1` in first line and compile the Server again :)